# mysql c api mysql query function dosn't work

Tags: mysql, c

I spend 3 hours to figure out what is my problem in this code and why mysql_query doesn't work...
this is my query:

```
`sprintf(quer, "INSERT INTO `tblRobotProcessQueue`(ProcessId,Protocol,SRC_IP,DST_IP,SRC_Port,DST_Port,`HostName`,`URL`,`Href`,DateAdd) VALUES(%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%s,%s,%s,%d )" ,pid*i, 6, 1234, 5345, 80, 44, "HostName", "URL", "Href", currentTime);`
```

---

and here is my customize db_query :

```
int _db_query(MYSQL *mysql_conn, char* sql ) {
    int ret = 0;

    if ( 0 == ( ret = mysql_ping( mysql_conn ) ) ) {

        if(!mysql_query( mysql_conn , sql )){
            PTRACE(0,0, "mysql_query can't run");
        }

        printf("ret is : %d\n", ret);

        //syslog ( LOG_INFO , "db_query( %u , [%s] )" , connection_id , sql );
        if ( 0 != ret && NULL != mysql_error( mysql_conn ) ) {

            syslog ( LOG_INFO , "Mysql query connection %s", mysql_error( mysql_conn ) );
            PTRACE(0,0, "FAIL HERE IN _DB_QUERY");
        }

    } else {
        PTRACE( 0 , 0 , "Mysql Ping Error connection %s" ,mysql_error( mysql_conn ) );

    }
    PTRACE(0,0, "reach to end of _db_query...\n");
    return ret;
}
```

---

when i run my program i can see some data added in my table with phpmysqladnin
but this part execute in my terminal: `PTRACE(0,0, "mysql_query can't run");`
help me guys!

Comment: If the `mysql_query` function fail, then perhaps you should check the error? And please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: mysql_error() just return a blank line! it's so strange for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!mysql_query( mysql_conn , sql )){
    PTRACE(0,0, "mysql_query can't run");
}
```

This part is the problem. `mysql_query` returns `0` when it succeeds and a strictly negative value when it fails. So your condition prints an error message when the function actually succeeds. Indeed `if (!functionCall())` is actually the same as `if (functionCall() == 0)`.

You should change it too :

```
if(mysql_query( mysql_conn , sql ) < 0){
    PTRACE(0,0, "mysql_query can't run");
}
```